# How to insert data in mongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, java-8

I want to write and read from a mongodb database. To create an entry, I use the following code:

```
private void updateMongoDb(TagEnum tag, BigDecimal minLen, BigDecimal maxLen,
                      List<BigDecimal> defaultLengths,
                      List<Double> lengthMultipliers, boolean useLengthMultipliers) {
    TagPreferences tagPreferences  = new TagDepositPreferences();
    tagPreferences.setProvider(tag);
    tagPreferences.setMinLen(minLen);
    tagPreferences.setMaxLen(maxLen);
    tagPreferences.setDefaultLengths(defaultLengths);
    tagPreferences.setLengthMultipliers(lengthMultipliers);
    tagPreferences.setUseLengthMultipliers(useLengthMultipliers);

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("tag").is(tag));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("minLen").is(minLen));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("maxLen").is(maxLen));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("defaultLengths").is(defaultLengths));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("lengthMultipliers").is(lengthMultipliers));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("useLengthMultipliers").is(useLengthMultipliers));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.setOnInsert(tagPreferences.CREATED_AT, Instant.now());
    update.set(tagPreferences.LAST_MODIFIED_AT, Instant.now());
    update.set("tag", tagPreferences.getTag());
    update.set("minLen", tagPreferences.getMinLen());
    update.set("maxLen", tagPreferences.getMaxLen());
    update.set("defaultLengths", tagPreferences.getDefaultLengths());
    update.set("useLengthMultipliers", tagPreferences.isUseLengthMultipliers());
    update.set("lengthMultipliers", tagPreferences.getLengthMultipliers());

    mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, TagPreferences.class);
}
```

and to read from it, I have a repository class with a method

```
TagPreferences findAllByTag(TagEnum tag);
```

And I do:

```
 TagPreferences tagPreferences = tagPreferencesRepository.findAllByTag(TagEnum tag);
```

The problem is that while I execute `updateMongoDb` only once, when I execute the `findAllByTag()` method I always get three results with the same values, instead of one. It would be really helpful if you could please explain the root cause behind that, and suggest corrections.

Comment: What does `findAllByTag` do?

Comment: Its definition is:                                          List<TagPreferences> findAllByTag(TagEnum tag);                                                                                             It returns a list of TagPreferences objects that match the requirements of the parameter passed when the method is called. The issue is that when I insert only one TagPreferences object of TagEnum x, and then call findAllByTag(x), instead of getting back a list containing one object, I get 3.

Comment: Are there multiple documents in the database with `x`, or is the findAllByTag duplicating the response?

Comment: Thank you. I had added multiple entries while I was developing the program. I created a method to remove them (   void deleteAllByTag(TagEnum tagEnum); and then added only the entries I wanted and now I get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe gave the solution in the commenting section. The issue was that after repetitive runs of the program, the mongo database had been filled with unrelated entries. This is resolved by creating a

```
void deleteAllByTag(TagEnum tagEnum);
```

method on the `TagPreferencesRepository` and calling it from inside the `updateMongoDb()` method, on the top.